# How to create a numpy array from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I import a txt file with

```
np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype='str')
```

I could for example get the following numpy array

```
['aaa' 'aaa' 'a']
```

What i would like to end up with is a numpy array looking like this

```
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

Take in mind, that the text file has only 1 a in the last row, so the script should automatically add another 2 a's to match the longest list in the array.

i've managed to make commas between the 3 strings with

```
[s.replace(' ', ',') for s in file]
```

But this doesn't seem to work if i would replace the space with ][.

any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you have `['aaa' 'abc' 'a']`

Comment: then it would return a numpy array like this

    [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]

only value 'a' would return if there was no value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func(file_name):
  arr = np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype='str')
  # this line is in case you omitted the ',' between strings in loaded numpy array from your question
  # arr = arr.tolist().split() 
  l = []
  for i in arr:
    el = list(i)
    while len(el) < 3:
      el.append('a')
    l.append(el)
return np.array(l)
```

I hope this is ok for you.

Comment: Can you explain to me how to do this with only a list? because when i try this on a list, i get an error. I redo this another way and i ge the right answer until i put np.array on it, then i has no commas in the numpy array

Comment: Can you explain your question a little better? I'm not sure I understand what you're asking me

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```
str = "'aaa' 'aaa' 'a'"
str2 = str.replace("'a'","'a' 'a' 'a'")
str3 = str2.replace("'aaa' ","'a' 'a' 'a',")
str4 = str3.replace("'aaa'","'a' 'a' 'a',")
my_data2 = [str4.split(',') for x in str4.split('|')]
print(my_data2)
```

NOTE: Sorry for my basic reply, it's my very first answer. Hope that helped.

EDIT

```
[s.replace("'a'","'a','a','a'") for s in file] # add 3 'a's at the last one
[s.replace("'aaa' ","'a','a','a' ") for s in file] # split each one of the 3 'aaa's in the first to items
[s.split(" ") for s in file] # create 3 item "'a', 'a', 'a'" list per line
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what im looking for. Im looking for a piece of code where i could write in my file name and it would give me the desired numpy array. I already made it as far as described, but need the last bit.

Answer (score 0):

Usig a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt(filename, dtype='str')
mValue = len(max(data, key=lambda x: len(x)))
print([[j for j in i.ljust(mValue, i[0])] for i in data])
```